# Умножение в столбик

Tags: c++, алгоритм, длинная-арифметика

Как написать оператор `*=` для длинных беззнаковых чисел методом умножения в столбик (длинная арифметика) без использования оператора `*`, если числа хранятся в виде массивов цифр по некоторому основанию `base` задом наперёд? Везде есть реализация `*`, а для `*=` не нашёл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто "на месте" у вас вряд ли получится - нужна будет перезапись тех элементов, которые все еще потребуются для вычислений. Т.е. `*=` не будет ни эффективнее, ни менее затратно в смысле памяти.

Поэтому лучше реализовывать `*`, а потом присваивать (например, оператором перемещающего присваивания).

Comment: Точно не получится выделить меньше памяти?

Comment: Думаю, что не получится. Абсолютную гарантию дать не могу - например, ценой каких-то хитрых вычислений, использующих уже вычисленные значения, которые затерли исходные... Но даже если это и возможно - то это настолько усложнит программу, что никакого смысла в этой экономии (ну сколько вы реально сэкономите?...) нет.

Comment: @naomi, ну, теоретически, при некоторых реализациях получится - если скопировать множитель, а не результат, то он будет содержать меньше разрядов. Однако, присваивание внутренних указателей вместо копирования самих чисел позволит это делать ещё более эффективно - без выделения лишней памяти.

Comment: @Harry ладно, теперь буду спать спокойно